# styling the actionbar with background color

Tags: android

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

I've added this to my manifest

```
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

I'm trying to style my actionbar but the below isn't working can anyone help me to understand why.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you using this with the actionbar?

Comment: use the toolbar instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I just wanted to change the background colour of my action bar

Comment: set AppTheme to your activity theme from the Manifest

Comment: What's the minimum API level of your application?

Comment: **@sim,** android recently introduces toolbar widget. Google it. I'm sure u'll love it.

Comment: @PM25793, she'll have to change the whole thing. It's not worth it when all she needs is to change the color.

Comment: **@tushar** be always ready to learn new thing :)

Comment: @tushar is there a simple solution for me to change the color

Comment: @sim don't forget to vote up, if you find anything useful.

Comment: @Sim you can simply do this in `onCreate()` like this: `ActionBar bar = getActionBar();`
`bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));`

Comment: Will this have to be done in every activity in my app?

Comment: Wherever you need it.

Comment: This actually kills my application from running

Comment: Can you post the logcat? Must be nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the theme in the manifest?

Your application tag in the manifest should be something like below:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Action Bar xml styling only works for API<11:

If you want to set Actiobar Color can also be defined in .class file, the snippet is:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

Remember this snippet only works for API>11

Hope this help you.

Comment: how would I add icons if this is the way it needs to be defined?

Comment: By using `bar.setIcon(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_NAME);`

Comment: `bar.setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);`